# Workspace relative linked resources folder

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

in an Eclipse plugin, is it possibile to create a linked resource **relative to the workspace and not to a project** (I mean programmatically).

In this example

https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresInt_linked.htm

I need the project to get the folder:

```
IProject project = workspace.getProject("Project");//assume this exists
IFolder link = project.getFolder("Link");
```

Is it possible to do it from the workspace root?

`ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()`

I need to use the folder as a temporary folder for all the projects.
Is there any other way of doing this??
Thank you very much!

Comment: No, all resources in the workspace must be in a project. Plug-ins can use the 'state location' in the workspace .metadata to store things they don't want to expose in projects.

Comment: Thank you @greg-449, in fact I'm using the state location. I will create a folder for every project inside that location.

Comment: Note - you just use the standard Java file I/O APIs for files and directories in the state location. IProject, IFolder, IFile are not used for that.

Comment: Yes true, but I have created a linked resource from each project pointing to the right folder, so that I can use IFolder IFile and IDocument APIs. This is possible because the files become "member" of the project...

Comment: If you are creating a link in the project why use the state location at all - why not just create the resource in the project? Maybe use `IResource.setDerived` to mark it as a derived resource.

Comment: I need a folder for temporary files, that can be in the project but it should not be visible... 
If I use an hidden resource is not visible, but points to some existing folder in the project directory. So how to hide that folder??

Comment: IResource has a `setHidden` method, but it is rarely used. Project/Package explorer normally hide folders with names starting with '.' but this can be turned off.